# Page stopped scrolling

Tags: html, css

I do not understand what happened but suddenly my page do not scroll down to view the rest of the content...

check it out: [www.guestinnation.com/hotels.html](http://www.guestinnation.com/hotels.html)

As you can see using the inspect element functionality, the div is much longer than it appears...

Before this I had set a height for the div of `60%` of the page and used the overflow:scroll, but then i decided that I simply wanted it to be like the homepage, so I cancelled the `height=60%` and overflow:scroll, but it ended up being like you see...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, why can't you use overflow: scroll?
also can you provide some html and CSS? specifically the divs affected?

Comment: everything has `position:fixed;` on it...

Comment: @Gnuey it's not a div, it's the whole page... it's the browser page that is missing the scrolling bar, not a single DIV... 
Like in this page we are reading now on Stackoverflow, if I want to see the full content of the page I simply scroll down, right? How is it in my website I can not scroll down to see the content below?

#main {
 width:700px;
 position:fixed;
 top:180px;
 left:50%;
 margin-left: -350px;
 clear:both;
 display:block;
 background-color: white;
 -moz-border-radius: 15px;
 border-radius: 15px;
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px gray inset;
 padding: 0px 20px 25px 20px;
}

Answer (score 2):

**Edited**

change two position on your css :

```
#main{
  position: relative; // change it from fixed
}
#menumain2 {
  position: absolute; // change it from fixed
}
#menumain {
  position: absolute; // change it from fixed
}
```

Comment: But the line below the `#menumain2` is still there which should not be there.

Answer (score 1):

Do this :

```
#main
{
   position: relative;
}
#menumain
{
   position: absolute; 
}
#menumain2 
{
   position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your page scroll is gone because you used `position: fixed;` to center your main content. that means that the element is positioned relative to the browser window.

Try something like that for a mock-up.

```
<body>
      <div id="wrapper">
            <header></header>
            <div id="main"></div>
            <footer></footer>
      </div>
</body>

.wrapper{
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative /* Just in case */
      width: 960px; }
```

That's how I'll start.

Or if you have problems starting a website try some HTML starter packs, the web is full of them.